# Find all functions $f$ such that $f(x)\sin(1/x)$ continuous at $x_0 = 0$

Tags: calculus

A high-school problem. There is a mistake with the problem setting since $f(x)\sin(1/x)$ is undefined at $x=0$. You may alternatively use the limit here. The problem would thus become finding all functions $f$ such that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)\sin(1/x)$ exists.

Comment: Any polynomial whose $x^0$ coefficient is $(0)$ will work for $f(x)$.  There certainly could be other satisfying functions.

Comment: The limit exists if $f(x) \to 0$ as $x\to 0$. Question is, can $f$ behave differently?

Comment: @AlvinL There will be functions $\not \to 0$ such as $f(x)=0$ when $x=0$, $f(x)=\frac1x$ when  $x=\frac{1}{2\pi n}$ for any integer $n$, and $f(x)=\frac x{\sin(1/x)}$ for other $x$.

Comment: @Henry Does $f(x)\sin (\frac{1}{x})$ continuous for your $f$?

Comment: @bFur4list my $f(x)\sin (\frac{1}{x})$ would be continuous at $x=0$ since it is always between $-x$ and $x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Find all the function $\,f\!:\!\big[\!-1,1\big]\to\mathbb R\,$ such that there exists $\,\lim_\limits{x\to0}f(x)\sin\left(\dfrac1x\right)=l\in\mathbb R\,.$

We will prove that

If $\,f\!:\!\big[\!-\!1,1\big]\!\to\!\mathbb R\,$ is a function such that there exists $\lim_\limits{x\to0}f(x)\sin\left(\!\dfrac1x\!\right)=l\in\mathbb R\;,\;$ then

$f(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{g(x)}{\sin\left(\frac1x\right)}\qquad\text{if }\;x\in\big[-1,1\big]\setminus A\\\\h(x)\qquad\quad\text{ if }\;x\in A\end{cases}$

where $\,g\!:\!\big[\!-\!1,1\big]\!\to\!\mathbb R\,$ is a function such that $\,\lim_\limits{x\to0}g(x)=0\,,\,$ $A=\left\{\dfrac1{\lambda\pi}\,,\;\lambda\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}\right\}\cup\big\{0\big\}\;$ and $\;\;h:A\to\mathbb R\;$ is a real function defined on $\,A\,.\\$

***Proof :***

Let $\,x_n=\dfrac1{2n\pi}\in\big]0,1\big[\;$ for any $\,n\in\mathbb N\,.$

Since $\,\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}x_n=0\,,\,$ by applying the sequential Criterion for a limit of a function, we get that

$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}f(x_n)\sin\left(\dfrac1{x_n}\right)=l\in\mathbb R\,.$

On the other hand, it results that

$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}f(x_n)\sin\left(\dfrac1{x_n}\right)=\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}f(x_n)\sin\left(2n\pi\right)=0\,.$

Hence, by applying the Uniqueness of limits Theorem, it follows that $\,l=0\,,\,$ consequently ,

$\lim_\limits{x\to0}f(x)\sin\left(\!\dfrac1x\!\right)\!=\!0\,.$

Let $\,A\!=\!\left\{\!\dfrac1{\lambda\pi}\,,\;\lambda\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}\!\right\}\!\cup\!\big\{0\big\}\;$ and let $\;h:\!A\to\mathbb R\;$ be the function defined as $\;h(x)=f(x)\;$ for all $\;x\in A\,.$

Now we define the function $\,g\!:\!\big[-1,1\big]\to\mathbb R\,$ as follows

$g(x)=\begin{cases} f(x)\sin\left(\!\dfrac1x\!\right)\qquad\text{if }\;x\in\big[-1,1\big]\setminus\big\{0\big\}\\\beta\in\mathbb R\qquad\qquad\text{ if }\;x=0\end{cases}$

It results that $\,\lim_\limits{x\to0}g(x)=0\,,\,$ moreover ,

$f(x)=\dfrac{g(x)}{\sin\left(\frac1x\right)}\quad\forall\,x\in\big[\!-\!1,1\big]\setminus A\;,$

$f(x)=h(x)\quad$ for all $\;x\in A\,.$

---

Now we will prove that

If $\,f\!:\!\big[\!-\!1,1\big]\!\to\!\mathbb R\,$ is a function such that

$f(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{g(x)}{\sin\left(\frac1x\right)}\qquad\text{if }\;x\in\big[-1,1\big]\setminus A\\\\h(x)\qquad\quad\text{ if }\;x\in A\end{cases}$

where $\,g\!:\!\big[\!-\!\!1,\!1\big]\!\!\to\!\mathbb R\,$ is any function such that $\,\lim_\limits{x\to0}g(x)=0\,,$ $A=\left\{\dfrac1{\lambda\pi}\,,\;\lambda\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}\right\}\cup\big\{0\big\}\;$ and $\;\;h:A\to\mathbb R\;$ is any real function defined on $\,A\,,\,$ then

$\,\exists\lim_\limits{x\to0}f(x)\sin\left(\!\dfrac1x\!\right)\!=\!l\!\in\!\mathbb R\;.$

***Proof :***

Since $\; f(x)\sin\left(\!\dfrac1x\!\right)\!=\!g(x)\quad\forall\;x\in\big[\!-\!1,1\big]\!\setminus A\;\;,$

$f(x)\sin\left(\!\dfrac1x\!\right)\!=\!h(x)\sin\left(\lambda\pi\right)=0\quad\forall\;x\in A\setminus\{0\}$

and $\;\lim_\limits{x\to0}g(x)=0\;,\;$ it follows that

$\exists\lim_\limits{x\to0}f(x)\sin\left(\!\dfrac1x\!\right)=0=l\in\mathbb R\,.$

---

Consequently, all the function $\,f\!:\!\big[\!-1,1\big]\to\mathbb R\,$ such that there exists $\,\lim_\limits{x\to0}f(x)\sin\left(\dfrac1x\right)=l\in\mathbb R\;,\;$ are the following ones :

$f(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{g(x)}{\sin\left(\frac1x\right)}\qquad\text{if }\;x\in\big[-1,1\big]\setminus A\\\\h(x)\qquad\quad\text{ if }\;x\in A\end{cases}$

where $\,g\!:\!\big[\!-\!\!1,\!1\big]\!\!\to\!\mathbb R\,$ is any function such that $\,\lim_\limits{x\to0}g(x)=0\,,$ $A=\left\{\dfrac1{\lambda\pi}\,,\;\lambda\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}\right\}\cup\big\{0\big\}\;$ and $\;\;h:A\to\mathbb R\;$ is any real function defined on $\,A\,.$

---

***Addendum :***

A subset of the set of all the function $\,f\!:\!\big[\!-1,1\big]\to\mathbb R\,$ such that there exists $\,\lim_\limits{x\to0}f(x)\sin\left(\dfrac1x\right)=l\in\mathbb R\;,\;$ is

$S=\left\{\varphi\!:\!\big[\!-\!1,1\big]\!\to\!\mathbb R\;\text{ such that }\;\exists\lim_\limits{x\to0}\varphi(x)=0\right\}.$

***Proof :***

Let $\,\varphi\!:\!\big[\!-\!1,1\big]\!\to\!\mathbb R\,$ be any function such that $\,\lim_\limits{x\to0}\varphi(x)=0\,.$

We will prove that $\;f=\varphi:\big[-1,1\big]\to\mathbb R\;$ is a function such that there exists $\,\lim_\limits{x\to0}f(x)\sin\left(\dfrac1x\right)=l\in\mathbb R\;.$

All the function $\,f\!:\!\big[\!-1,1\big]\to\mathbb R\,$ such that there exists $\,\lim_\limits{x\to0}f(x)\sin\left(\dfrac1x\right)=l\in\mathbb R\;,\;$ are the following ones :

$f(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{g(x)}{\sin\left(\frac1x\right)}\qquad\text{if }\;x\in\big[-1,1\big]\setminus A\\\\h(x)\qquad\quad\text{ if }\;x\in A\end{cases}$

where $\,g\!:\!\big[\!-\!\!1,\!1\big]\!\!\to\!\mathbb R\,$ is any function such that $\,\lim_\limits{x\to0}g(x)=0\,,$ $A=\left\{\dfrac1{\lambda\pi}\,,\;\lambda\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}\right\}\cup\big\{0\big\}\;$ and $\;\;h:A\to\mathbb R\;$ is any real function defined on $\,A\,.$

If $\,g\!:\!\big[\!-\!\!1,1\big]\!\!\to\!\mathbb R\,$ is the real function defined as

$g(x)=\begin{cases}\varphi(x)\sin\left(\dfrac1x\right)\qquad\text{if }\;x\in\big[\!-\!1,1\big]\setminus\big\{0\big\}\\\;\;0\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{if }\;x=0\end{cases}$

and if $\;h:A\to\mathbb R\;$ is the real function defined as

$h(x)=\varphi(x)\quad$ for all $\;x\in A\;,$

then it results that

$\lim_\limits{x\to0}g(x)=\lim_\limits{x\to0}\varphi(x)\sin\left(\dfrac1x\right)=0\;\;$ and

$f(x)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{g(x)}{\sin\left(\frac1x\right)}=\varphi(x)\qquad\text{if }\;x\in\big[-1,1\big]\setminus A\\\\h(x)=\varphi(x)\qquad\quad\text{ if }\;x\in A\end{cases}$

Hence ,

$f=\varphi:\big[-1,1\big]\to\mathbb R\;$ is a function such that there exists $\,\lim_\limits{x\to0}f(x)\sin\left(\dfrac1x\right)=l\in\mathbb R\;.$

Comment: My word, high school math is mighty sophisticated these days.

Comment: @AlvinL, I am sure you could answer the original poster’s question in such a way that high school mathematics becomes a little less sophisticated. Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=f(x)\sin\frac{1}{x}$ and $g(0)=0.$
We show that $$g(x)=x^2\sin\frac{1}{x}$$ is continuous at $x=0.$.
We find $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)=0$ by sandwich theorem by noting that
$$-x^2\le x^2\sin \frac{1}{x}\le x^2\implies \lim_{x \to 0} -x^2= \lim_{x \to 0} x^2 \sin \frac{1}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0} x^2$$
Next,  $$\frac{dg(x)}{dx}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{h^2\sin \frac{1}{h}-0}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} h \sin \frac{1}{h}=0, $$
by sandwich theorem as
$$-x\le x\sin \frac{1}{x}\le x\implies \lim_{x \to 0} -x= \lim_{x \to 0} x \sin \frac{1}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0} x=0.$$

Hence $g(x)$ when $f(x)=x^2$ is both continuous and differentiable at $x=0.$